# ju plu... des pli

Tags: word-usage

Laŭ [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#ju) kaj [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/ju.html#ju.0) *ju* estas uzata kun *pli* kaj *malpli*. [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/ju_des.html) asertas, ke *ju* estas ĉiam uzata kune kun *pli* aŭ *malpli*. Tamen, mi trovis ekzemplojn pri uzado de *ju* kune kun *plu*, kiuj al mi ne ŝajnas skriberaro de la aŭtoro. Jen ili (vortemfazo estas mia):

> [`Tekstaro`](https://www.tekstaro.com/):
>
> [...] **ju pluen** li iris, **des pli** malfacile fariĝis trabati al
>   li la vojon
>
> ---
>
> [`Unuetaĝa Usono`](http://www.esperanto.mv.ru/Usono/truu44.html) `(de Ilja Ilf, Evgenij Petrov. Elrusigis Vladimir Okc)`:
>
> **Ju plu** ni penetris la Sudajn ŝtatojn, **des pli** ofte ni vidis diversajn obstaklojn por negroj.

La unua frazo uzas [*plue* en direkta signifo](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/plu.html#i-j9a) kaj kun direkta N-finaĵo. La dua frazo uzas [lokan *plu*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/plu.html#i-f7p), montrante daŭrigon tempan kaj lokan.

La frazoj estus same kompreneblaj se oni dirus *ju pli li iris* kaj *ju pli ni penetris*, sed mi opinias, ke la uzado de *plu* donas nuancon, kiun la partikulo *pli* ne kapablas esprimi tiel klare en ĉi frazoj:

*ju pluen li iris*... = *ju pli li daŭre kaj loke (ien) iris*...

*ju plu ni penetris*... =  *ju pli ni daŭre kaj loke penetris*...

Jen mia demando: Ĉu la uzado de *ju plu* estas lingve ĝusta, eĉ se PMEG asertas ke *ju* estas ĉiam uzata kune kun *pli*?

Answer (score 1):

*pli* temas pri kvanto, grado. Kaj ĝi rilatas kaj adjektivojn kaj adverbojn.

La konstruo *ju ... des* kunligas la ŝanĝiĝon de kvanto/grado inter du esprimoj. La *ju* parto estas la ĉefa ŝanĝiĝo, kaj la *des* parto, la dependa.

*Ju pli mi legas, des pli mi komprenas*.

Sed, *plu* temas pri daŭro, neĉeso.

*ju plu ... des pli* estas, laŭ mi, eraro. Iel komprenebla, ĉar kelkaj uzas *plu* kvazaŭ estus adverba paro de pli (kio postulus ke _pli_nur rilatu adjektivojn, kio ne estas vera).

Answer (score 1):

Ĉio indikas ke *ju plu(e/en)* estas gramatike malĝusta, ke devas esti *ju pli*. Tamen, eĉ PMEG iafoje agnoskas nelogikan uzadon de diversaj aferoj en la lingvo. Jen ekzemplo:

> [`PMEG, Mallogika uzo de direkta N`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/n/direkto.html#i-dn4)
>
> Direkta N aperas ankaŭ en vortoj kiel *pluen, renkonten, tiudirekten,
>   reen* k.s., kie la N-finaĵo principe estas mallogika, ĉar *plu,
>   renkonte, tiudirekte* kaj *ree* ne montras lokon. Iafoje tia mallogika
>   uzo tamen helpas al klareco, kaj tiaj esprimoj ne estas nepre
>   evitendaj.

Eble temas pri subkomprenata *pli*:

*ju pluen li iris...* → *ju pli li pluen iris... des pli...*

*ju plu ni penetris...* → *ju pli ni plu penetris... des pli...*

Eble la sona simileco inter *pli* kaj *plu* estas la kialo, pro kio la verkistoj forlasis *pli*, mi vere ne scias. La demando estas: ĉu per tiu forlaso la signifo estas tute klara? Por mi ĝi estas, kaj ŝajne ankaŭ por la du verkistoj (supoze ke temas pri intenca forlaso kaj ne pri mistajpo).